# Angular 4: Displaying td value based upon condition

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular.

Below is my HTML code:

```
  <tr *ngFor="let item of calendarTableSelected;let idx = index" >
                                    <span *ngIf="idx  === 0">
                                        <td style="width:15%;" *ngFor="let name of item.results" [(ngModel)]="name.value" name="promoOne" ngDefaultControl >  
                                         <span  *ngIf="name.value">
                                            <label style="color:blue;"> &#9679;</label>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                  </span>
                                </tr>
                                <tr *ngFor="let item of calendarTableSelected;let idx = index" >
                                        <span *ngIf="idx  === 1">
                                            <td style="width:15%;" *ngFor="let name of item.results" [(ngModel)]="name.value" name="promoOne" ngDefaultControl >  
                                                <label style="color:red;"> &#9679;</label>

                                        </td>
                                      </span>
                                </tr>
```

I want if the value in "td"  binded to name.value is not null, only then it should execute the statement:

```
   <label style="color:blue;"> &#9679;</label>
```

But I am not able to figure out how to do that.
Please help.

Comment: What's not working with what you've got?

Comment: @user184994 I want another if condition here so that if the value in td is null, it should not display the blue color in the cell, like the way I have written the code below.                                                          
                                            <td style="width:15%;" *ngFor="let name of item.results" [(ngModel)]="name.value" name="promoOne" ngDefaultControl >  
 <ng-container  *ngIf="name.visible">
 <label style="color:blue;"> &#9679;</label> </ng-container></td>

Comment: please read if else condition of angular

Comment: @SharmaVikram there is no else condition in angular. Moreover, how you can write if condition in the td component over another "if" and "for" condition is the challenge here.

Comment: ma'am angular 2,4,5 supports if else conditions

Comment: you can read this doc 
https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Can you create a basic plunkr / stackblitz showing what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: name.value null means you want to show blue color and if it is not null  you want to show red color ?

Comment: @ArunKumaresh No actually. Red color is for the second row so we can ignore it as of now, If the value coming from json is not null, it should show blue color otherwise it should show empty

Comment: Here is a stackblitz, is this what you mean? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxqsfv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *ngIf to check wheather the value is null or not check the below example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwj1py?file=app%2Fapp.component.html